# Runtime Error in c program

Tags: c

The following code is giving runtime error and i just can't find what's wrong in the code.So if anyone can help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    while(1){
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a==42)
            break;  
        printf("%d\n",a);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to use the debugger. And `void main()` is an illegal signature.

Comment: I can see how this program could hang on invalid input, but I am not sure how it would crash.

Comment: `void main() {` --> `int main(void) {` ..... `return 0;`

Comment: Do you mean "why does it print `0` forever when I enter `abc` instead of a number?"

Comment: I test it and it hang on characters input.

Comment: when you enter characters like `'a'` `scanf` waiting for number so skip it and continue to loop so it hang and print the last value of a until you enter a valid number so if you want to read character with `scanf` try to use `%c` instead of `%d`.

Comment: If `scanf` finds input it cannot process, such as `abc` when it requires a number, the input remains in the buffer, and `scanf` keeps banging head against wall. Please test the return value from `scanf`. It tells you how many items were scanned.

Comment: Show your input.

Comment: @himanshu Show your input  which resulted in runtime error

Comment: Actually I run this on Ideone and it is giving runtime error without any input @Binary_10

Comment: If you haven't specified any input, scanf  returns `EOF` and loop prints value of `a` onto console continuously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan the user input until it press valid input you can use following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a = 0;
    while(1){
        scanf("%c",&a);
        if(a==42)
            break;  
        printf("%d\n",a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not hang on any input but it process inputs character by character so you may see something like `10` printed on your console because of you enters. To end this program valid user input is `*` if we have ascii coding.

As you can see in `scanf` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> On success, these functions return the number of input items
>          successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided
>          for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

it will return number of successfully matched inputs so you can check this value to insure that you code will have progress on input buffer.

Comment: That would mean users would (if ASCII coding) have to type `*` to end the program.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for mentation that, I added into my answer.